# File name is converting to lowercase in j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, file-upload

i have a code which will upload a file to the Tomcat server everything works fine but, the name of the file is converting to lowercase.

eg:- if we upload DealerINModule.txt file, it is converting to dealerinmodule.txt on server side.

so, is there any method in j2ee to get the same(filename) case as we have uploaded in server.
eg in our case  we are uploading file name DealerINModule.txt should not be converted into
dealerinmodule.txt...

// Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName().toString();
            System.out.println("fieldname:"+fieldName);
           // String fileName = request.getParameter("jar");
            String fileName = fi.getName().toString();

```
        //String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(openFile.getName());
        //String fileName=    new File("D://data/ApnaKhataIN").getName();
        System.out.println("filename:"+fileName);
        String contentType = fi.getContentType();
        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

        int lastIndexOfSlash = fileName.lastIndexOf("\\");
        System.out.println("file name: "+fileName); 
        if(fileName.equals("")) 
            continue; // do not process if file not selected
        System.out.println("file last index of slash: "+ lastIndexOfSlash); 

        // Write the file
        if( lastIndexOfSlash >= 0 ){
           file = new File( filePath +"/".trim()+ fileName.substring( lastIndexOfSlash).trim()) ;
          fileexist=file.exists();

          //delete if file exist
         /* if(fileexist)
          {
             file.delete();
              response.getWriter().print("oldfile is deleted");
          }*/
        }
```

Comment: Why are you sure that this is a server side issue and not a client side issue?

Comment: Obiviously that is written in java code..... and i have printed it in my console while deploying in server

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Nothing in your original question or your very late follow up comment demonstrates that this is a server side issue rather than a client side one. Hint: Wireshark is your friend.

Comment: ya you are correct actually i am getting filename only in loiwer case . . .Is their any alternative method of getting filename in j2ee.System.out.println("file name: "+fileName);